# Need to Setup Radius Server with Google Authenticator on Rocky 9 and Create Custom attribute for Different Network Devices

Tags: attributes, user-controls, google-oauth, freeradius, pam

*#For Dell Switch Admin User
*Testuser Cleartext-Password := "XXXXXX"

- ```
          Force10-avpair= "shell:role=sysadmin"
  ```

*#For Dell Switch Operator User
*Testuser1 Cleartext-Password := "XXXXXX"

- ```
          Force10-avpair= "shell:role=netoperator"
  ```

*#For Huawei Switch Admin User

*Testuser Cleartext-Password := "XXXXXX"

- ```
    Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
  ```
- ```
     # RADIUS Attribute
  ```
- ```
           Huawei-Exec-Privilege = "3",
  ```
- ```
                     # Login-Service 50 is for SSH
  ```
- ```
                          Login-Service = 50
  ```

*For Huawei Switch Operator User

*Testuser1 Cleartext-Password := "XXXXXX"

- ```
    Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
  ```
- ```
     # RADIUS Attribute
  ```
- ```
           Huawei-Exec-Privilege = "1",
  ```
- ```
                     # Login-Service 50 is for SSH
  ```
- ```
                          Login-Service = 50
  ```

*#using PAM authentication on freeradius server.

/etc/freeradius/users